# Create File within Finder [MacBook Pro M2]

Tags: macos, applescript, contextmenu, finder

Is there a way to create files outside of applications, but within the finder? Preferably with the context menu.

All I found were mentions about a **AppleScript**, but it was hidden behind a Paywall...

Comment: Welcome, Felix. We hope you reach your goal. In its current form though, your question is difficult to answer. As you've seen, that workflow is not possible without adding something to Finder. But then, what is your actual goal? Please Edit the question to include details of your goal, what other (non-scripting) app will eventually be involved, what you've tried, what didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone here gave you -1 because your question is not accurate. I will assume that you want to **create a new empty file with the Finder** to further fill it with some content. Here's how it's done.

```
tell application "Finder"
    make new file at desktop with properties {name:"emptyFile.html"}
end tell
```

**NOTE**: you can indicate any other name extension (like ".txt") instead.

Also, the desktop is default location, so you can to not indicate the location in the case you need create new file on it. Oneliner for this case:

```
tell application "Finder" to make new file with properties {name:"empty.txt"}
```